# What's the difference between [acentuación] and [diacríticos]?

Tags: discusión, soporte, etiquetas

1. What is the difference, if any, between the tag [acentuación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acentuaci%c3%b3n) and the tag [diacríticos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diacr%c3%adticos)?
2. If a question is correctly tagged with [acentuación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acentuaci%c3%b3n), then is the [ortografía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortograf%c3%ada) tag actually superfluous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 diacritics are broader in concept than accents but most diacritics in Spanish are accents.

2 accentuation is a proper subset of orthography but it does little harm to include it.

Comment: yup, and "acentuación" is applied towards pronunciation , while the "diacriticos" are the actual position of the orthographic mark.

You can have a "diacriticos" because you might not know if the accent has to be marked, or you might have an "accentuation" question because you don't know the right pronunciation.